# Why the var has to be inside the JS function?

Tags: javascript, function, return

I tried to use JS Function to calculate BMI.
My code is as below. When I tried to run it, it has this error:" Uncaught ReferenceError: weight is not defined."

Code:

```js
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
    return weight/(height**2);
}
var bmi = Math.round(bmiCalculator(weight, height));
console.log("My BMI is " + bmi);
 
bmiCalculator(65, 1.8);
```

If I put my var bmi inside the function, then I won't get this error. But I don't understand why I can't put my var bmi outside the function.

My thinking is:

- When the code run the var bmi line, it will take the output of function: bmiCalculator(weight, height) and round it to the nearest whole number, then this will be bmi.
- Then I can log the var bmi.

I don't understand why this won't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: weight, height doesn't exist as variable but is a parameter of function you need to do that:  `var bmi = Math.round(bmiCalculator(65, 1.8));`

Comment: Do the rounding inside the function. `return Math.round(weight/(height**2));` then call it with the numerical values.

Comment: What do you think `weight` and `height` in `Math.round(bmiCalculator(weight, height))` are…?

Comment: This question should not have been closed, imo. It is reproducible and it was not caused by typos. It is very much a newb question but it is still a legitimate question and is well posed.

Answer (score 1):

The error 'ReferenceError: weight is not defined' says it all.
The variable 'weight' is not defined. You're passing variables to the function bmiCalculator which is undefined. When you put it inside the function, it takes the passed argument in the function.

In your code snippet you're calling the function declared twice.

One here
`var bmi = Math.round(bmiCalculator(weight, height));`

The variable passed above in the function i.e. weight and height is not defined which is causing the error.

Second call
`bmiCalculator(65, 1.8);` which is correct.

You can fix it by declaring the used variable in first call or just pass the values.

```js
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
    return weight/(height**2);
}
//Passing the values
var bmi = Math.round(bmiCalculator(65, 1.8));
console.log("My BMI is " + bmi);
 /*This call is not required as it's not doing anything(returned value is not being used)*/
//bmiCalculator(65, 1.8);
```

Or, declare the variables

```js
function bmiCalculator(weight, height) {
    return weight/(height**2);
}

//Declaring the variables
var weight = 65;
var height  = 1.8;
var bmi = Math.round(bmiCalculator(weight, height));
console.log("My BMI is " + bmi);
 /*This call is not required as it's not doing anything(returned value is not being used)*/
//bmiCalculator(65, 1.8);
```